# appcfg.py upload_data ignores --oauth2 option on Windows

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to upload data on appengine application from Windows 7 PC using --oauth2 option. And it prompt me to enter credentials which fails.

```
D:\>appcfg.py --oauth2 --filename=dump.dump upload_data myApp/
10:07 PM Application: myApp
10:07 PM Uploading data records.
[INFO    ] Logging to bulkloader-log-20141228.220722
[INFO    ] Throttling transfers:
[INFO    ] Bandwidth: 250000 bytes/second
[INFO    ] HTTP connections: 8/second
[INFO    ] Entities inserted/fetched/modified: 20/second
[INFO    ] Batch Size: 10
[INFO    ] Opening database: bulkloader-progress-20141228.220722.sql3
[INFO    ] Connecting to myApp.appspot.com/remote_api
Please enter login credentials for myApp.appspot.com
Email: myEmail@gmail.com
Password for myEmail@gmail.com:
Invalid username or password.
```

However I expect it not to ask me about e-mail, like it happens during update:

```
D:\>appcfg.py --oauth2 update myApp/
10:06 PM Application: myApp; version: 1
10:06 PM Host: appengine.google.com
10:06 PM
Starting update of app: myApp, version: 1
10:06 PM Getting current resource limits.
10:06 PM Scanning files on local disk.
10:06 PM Cloning 1 static file.
10:06 PM Cloning 10 application files.
10:06 PM Compilation starting.
10:06 PM Compilation completed.
10:06 PM Starting deployment.
10:06 PM Checking if deployment succeeded.
10:06 PM Deployment successful.
10:06 PM Checking if updated app version is serving.
10:07 PM Completed update of app: myApp, version: 1
10:07 PM Uploading index definitions.
```

What's wrong with --oauth2 during upload_data?
If required, my app.yaml file looks this way:

```
application: myApp
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: no

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /remote_api
  script: $PYTHON_LIB/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/handler.py
  login: admin

- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
- name: jinja2
  version: "2.6"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the line

```
script: $PYTHON_LIB/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/handler.py
```

with (per https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/remoteapi at "Custom URL"):

```
script: google.appengine.ext.remote_api.handler.application
```

because you're using Python 2.7 according to the `runtime:` in your `app.yaml` file.

Comment: That did not change anything. Loks like an issue with credentials to access remote_api. Do I need to provde additional access rights to remote_api except Owner role?

Comment: Solved it by allowing access to less secure applications here: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps